# Finding the coefficients of $a^2\frac{\partial ^4u}{\partial x^4}+\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial t^2}=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Solving using the substitution $U=XT$ yields $X=c_1\cosh(\alpha x)+c_2\sinh(\alpha x)+c_3\cos(\alpha x)+c_4\sin(\alpha x)$ and $T=c_5\cos(\alpha^2at)+c_6\sin(\alpha^2at)$
From the boundary conditions $u(0,t)=0, u(L,t)=0$, I get 
$$c_1+c_3=0$$ and $$0=c_1\cosh(\alpha L)+c_2\sinh(\alpha L)+c_3\cos(\alpha L)+c_4\sin(\alpha L)$$
Supposedly, this simplifies to $c_1=c_3=0$ but I don't see how...

In case it matters I'll include the other conditions $X''(0)=X''(L)=0$, $u(x,0)=f(x)$ $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,0)=g(x)$

This question is from Zill's differential equations and BVP Chapter 12.4 #11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the conditions at $x=0$
$$X(0)=c_1+c_3=0\tag{1}$$
$$X^{\prime\prime}(0)=\alpha^2c_1-\alpha^2c_3=0\tag{2}$$
If we take $\alpha^2(1)+(2)$ we find that $2\alpha^2c_1=0$ so that $c_1=0$ and then from either equation it follows that $c_3=0$. With that knowledge we can move on to the conditions at $x=L$
$$X(L)=c_2\sinh\alpha L+c_4\sin\alpha L=0\tag{3}$$
$$X^{\prime\prime}(L)=\alpha^2c_2\sinh\alpha L-\alpha^2c_4\sin\alpha L=0\tag{4}$$
Again, $\alpha^2(3)+(4)$ reduces to $2\alpha^2c_2\sinh\alpha L=0$, so that $c_2=0$, but now equation $(4)$ reads $c_4\sin\alpha L=0$ which can be satisfied by $\alpha L=n\pi$, so that gives us our eigenvalues $\alpha_n=\frac{n\pi}L$. So we get a general solution
$$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a_n\cos\frac{n^2\pi^2at}{L^2}+b_n\sin\frac{n^2\pi^2at}{L^2}\right)\sin\frac{n\pi x}L$$
At $t=0$,
$$\begin{align}\int_0^Lu(x,0)\sin\frac{n\pi x}Ldx&=\int_0^Lf(x)\sin\frac{n\pi x}Ldx\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}a_m\int_0^L\sin\frac{m\pi x}L\sin\frac{n\pi x}Ldx\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}a_m\frac L2\delta_{mn}=\frac L2a_n\end{align}$$
So $$a_n=\frac2L\int_0^Lf(x)\sin\frac{n\pi x}Ldx$$
Also,
$$\begin{align}\int_0^L\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,0)\sin\frac{n\pi x}Ldx&=\int_0^Lg(x)\sin\frac{n\pi x}Ldx\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2\pi^2a}{L^2}b_m\int_0^L\sin\frac{m\pi x}L\sin\frac{n\pi x}Ldx\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2\pi^2a}{L^2}b_m\frac L2\delta_{mn}=\frac{n^2\pi^2a}{L^2}\frac L2b_n\end{align}$$
So $$b_n=\frac{2L}{n^2\pi^2a}\int_0^Lg(x)\sin\frac{n\pi x}Ldx$$

Comment: Perfect! Being roadblocked on this all day, I had to r

Comment: had to wait on some one to get me unstuck on the boundary conditions.